# How to find a document with highest count of related documents (user with most posts)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

What I'm trying to do is find the users with the most posts. `User` and `Post` are `Mongoid::Document`

The ActiveRecord equivalent of `User.group(posts)` doesn't work. I can access the number of posts a User has by `@user.posts.count`

How do I find the user with most posts, without sorting an array of all users by post count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoid collections respond to Array functions when you use :all.

```
User.all.max_by {|user| user.posts.count}
```

That iterates through all the Users and finds the User with the most posts.

Comment: Updated to fix my afternoon parlance inaccuracies.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! To expand on this, is there a way to see the top 5 users with the most posts? max_by only returns 1 document

Comment: For that you are better off following Sergio's suggestion and recording the post count. Then:

User.order_by(:post_count, :desc).all[0..4]

That will get the top 5. Mongoid doesn't support limit but if you use Mongodb directly you can use 'limit(5)'.

Mongoid also supports aggregations which is another way to do this: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#aggregations

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a way similar to SQL, where database does all the work, there ain't one. MongoDB has no joins and no SQL. If you leave your data model as it is, you can only iterate all users, fetch post count for them and then sort.

But you could eliminate this `N+1` query pattern by saving post count to a field in user document and keeping it actual (incrementing when new post added, etc). This is called "counter cache", there are [several plugins](https://www.google.ru/search?q=mongoid+counter+cache&aq=0&oq=mongoid+counter+cache&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for [mongoid](/questions/tagged/mongoid) that do this.

Once you have that cache column, you can sort on it without any problems.